# POSTing data on a small embedded device

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a mystery.html page that loads some javascript (as well as mootools).

I run a few calculations, and then I need to post this to a url. Seems simple, right?

Except:

- I dont have XMLHttpRequest
- I can't run createElement to create a FORM and dynamically add my data to it as inputs (and I can have anywhere from a few hundred elements to just one, so I can't pre-create them in my html)

my current thought is to create a FORM in my html with a single INPUT, then create a query string of my resulting parameters, add it to that INPUT, and submit that form. this will probably work, but smells inelegant.

any better suggestions/something obvious I'm missing?

update: turns out that document.write still works, so I can sort of hack my way around this way.

Comment: I think encoding all the data into one string, and putting that into the one input seems to be your best choice. Also, in mootools you can use `JSON.encode()` for this (I think that was the name of the method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really disclose more details about your target.
And of course, multiple fields in not a reason, because `document.urform.innerHTML += '<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="foo" VALUE="bar"><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="baz" VALUE="42">'` will do the work.

Comment: Woah. Brilliant and totally obvious. Thanks!

Comment: on second thought, it wont work. I dont have innerHTML, unfortunately. the entire DOM on this browser is completely immutable. I wonder if even the form idea would work at all.